# How do I convert hook_menu()?

Tags: 8, routes

I am having site built in Drupal 7 and in future I want to migrate my site to Drupal 8.

How can I write `hook_menu()` and `hook_menu_alter()` to routing.yml files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an example taken from [All functionality of hook_menu() is replaced by new systems for routing, menu links, local tasks, actions and contextual links](https://www.drupal.org/node/1800686):

**Drupal 7**

in modules/book/book.module:

```
function book_menu() {
   $items['book/export/%/%'] = array(
    'page callback' => 'book_export', 
    'page arguments' => array(2, 3), 
    'access arguments' => array('access printer-friendly version'), 
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK, 
    'file' => 'book.pages.inc',
  );
    $items['node/%node/outline'] = array(
    'title' => 'Outline', 
    'page callback' => 'book_outline', 
    'page arguments' => array(1), 
    'access callback' => '_book_outline_access', 
    'access arguments' => array(1), 
    'type' => MENU_LOCAL_TASK, 
    'weight' => 2, 
    'file' => 'book.pages.inc',
  );
...
  return $items;
}
```

**Drupal 8**

in modules/book/book.routing.yml:

```
book_export:
  pattern: '/book/export/{type}/{node}'
  defaults:
    # What's being returned is the entire response (not HTML, or even if HTML, we don't want additional blocks around it), so use _controller instead of _content.
    _controller: '\Drupal\book\BookController::export'
  requirements:
    _permission: 'access printer-friendly version'
book_node_outline:
  pattern: '/node/{node}/outline'
  defaults:
    _controller: '\Drupal\book\BookController::outline'
  requirements:
    # Indicates that the book outline access access system should be invoked.
    _book_outline_access: TRUE
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the [link of blog](https://www.drupal.org/node/1800686) to convert your `hook_menu` to `routing.yml` file.

Well to understand a simple routing.yml  :

```
route.name:
  path: '/path/of/page'
  defaults:
    _title: 'Title of Page'
    _controller: '\Drupal\modulename\Controller\ClassName::methodName'
  requirements:
    _permission: 'permission name'
```

This is an example of simple routing.yml file.

**route.name :** Name of route which should start with your module name.

**path :**  Path of the page.

**_title :** Title of page

**_controller :** Class that returns the content of page.

**_permission :** Permission of page.

To set the access_callback, parameter upcasting there are various different ways. To set the menu link and menu tab two more files that you have to write.

**webform.links.menu.yml** and **webform.links.task.yml**.